# I need to render just the submenu

Tags: 8

I need to print the current nodes submenu somewhere on the page. Inside my `page.twig.html` file I have this markup:

```
<div id="children-menu">
  {{menu_children}}
</div>
```

Inside my `mytheme_preprocess_page()` function I have this which rendering all the submenus.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->id()) {
    $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
    $menu_name = 'main';
    $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
    $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
    $manipulators = array(
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
      array('callable' => 'toolbar_menu_navigation_links'),
    );
    $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree,$manipulators);
    $subtrees = array();
    foreach ($tree as $element) {
      $link = $element->link;
      if ($element->subtree) {
        $subtree = $menu_tree->build($element->subtree);
        $output = drupal_render($subtree);
        array_push($subtrees, $output);
      }
    }
    //dpm($subtrees);
  }

}
```

I was looking into using manipulators, but that wasn't working. How can I render JUST the current nodes submenu using this function? Again, what I have now is rendering all the submenus and I need just the current one.

Comment: You shouldn't use `drupal_render` inside the preprocess function. TWIG can render the subtree itself, like so `{( $subtree }}`.

Comment: @eyal good to know, but still, it is rendering all sub menus when I just need the current pages sub menu

Comment: I'm not familiar with the menu tree functionality. But when I encounter such problems then I open the relevant classes and start reading the code to understand how they work.

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of `drupal_render()`.

Comment: @kenorb yup, you are correct. I answered my own question and you can see I did not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to grab just the child submenu of the current page. Each subtree has a `getRouteParameters()` fn that contains the node ID that it links to. I simply test if that route param node id == the current pages node id.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node']) && is_numeric($vars['node']->id())) {
    $nid = $vars['node']->id();
    $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
    $menu_name = 'main';
    $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
    $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
    $manipulators = array(
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
      array('callable' => 'toolbar_menu_navigation_links'),
    );
    $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree,$manipulators);
    $subtrees = array();
    foreach ($tree as $element) {
      $link = $element->link;
      if ($element->subtree) {
        $routeId = $element->link->getRouteParameters()['node'];
        if ($routeId == $nid) {
          $vars['menu_children'] = $menu_tree->build($element->subtree);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```